# how to set resource relations through annotations in Spring Hateoas?

Tags: java, spring, spring-hateoas

Is there a way to set resource relations through annotations? I made a similar question a some time ago but i've not been clear enough. I want to have something like this:

```
public class UserResource {

     private String username;

     @Relation(value = "{servicebaseUrl}/classes/${value}", rel = "class")
     private String classId;

     // Getters and setters
}
```

And then add a message converter which would add links only if client sends `Accept = application/hal+json`, avoiding  the fact of doing two different controller endpoints for `application/hal+json` and `application/json`. Does Spring offers something like that? I found that it actually offers this `@Relation` annotation(or similar one) but it seems that it is not for the same purposes.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible - you would have to implement a ResourceAssembler to add links to your resources.

Usually your resources extend `ResourceSupport`.

```
class PersonResource extends ResourceSupport {

  String firstname;
  String lastname;
}
```

Then your create `ResourceAssembler` to control the creation of that resource:

```
class PersonResourceAssembler extends ResourceAssemblerSupport<Person, PersonResource> {

  public PersonResourceAssembler() {
    super(PersonController.class, PersonResource.class);
  }

  @Override
  public PersonResource toResource(Person person) {

    PersonResource resource = createResource(person);
    // … do further mapping and add links 
    resource.add(new Link("http://myhost/people"));
    return resource;
  }
}
```

See the [spring hateoas documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/0.19.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#fundamentals.resource-assembler) for details

Comment: Maybe using ResourceAssembler would reduce links boilerplate, but i would still be using a controller endpoint for application/hal+json. so this wouldn't change the fact of having two different controller endpoints for the same resource. Thanks for your response!